# how to add a legend to a plot with two layers in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, legend

Here is codes of R.
When I run the following code, it does not have a legend. Could you help me figure out how to add a legend showing blue point and smooth are alzheimer and pinks are others? Thank you.

```
sct1 <- ggplot(human, aes(age1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = mean_alzheimer), colour = "deepskyblue") + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=mean_alzheimer), method="loess", , colour ="blue4", fill="gray") +
  geom_point(aes(y = mean_other), colour = 'deeppink3') +
  geom_smooth(aes( y=mean_other), method="loess", colour="red", fill="gray") 

sct2 <- sct1 +  scale_x_continuous("AGE", breaks=c( 38, 56, 72, 122, 270), labels=c("fetal", "infant", "child", "teen", "adult") ) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c (0, 270), ylim = c(-0.52,0.35))+
  scale_y_continuous("Expression ") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray","black")) +
  annotate("text", x=11, y=10, label="") +
  theme_bw()

optns <- theme (
  plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size=14),
  axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=12),
  axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12, angle=90),
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  legend.position = c(0.8,0.3),
  legend.title = element_blank(),
  legend.text = element_text(size=12),
  legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "lines"),
  legend.key = element_blank()
)

sct2 +  ggtitle ( "Alzheimer") + optns
```

IF I add the colour within aes(), the plot is strange. The colour is not exact what I defined.

```
sct1 <- ggplot(human, aes(age1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = mean_alzheimer, colour = "deepskyblue")) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=mean_alzheimer,  colour ="blue4"), method="loess", fill="gray") +
  geom_point(aes(y = mean_other, colour = 'deeppink3')) +
  geom_smooth(aes( y=mean_other, , colour="red"), method="loess", fill="gray") 

sct2 <- sct1 +  scale_x_continuous("AGE", breaks=c( 38, 56, 72, 122, 270), labels=c("fetal", "infant", "child", "teen", "adult") ) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c (0, 270), ylim = c(-0.52,0.35))+
  scale_y_continuous("Expression ") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray","black")) +
  annotate("text", x=11, y=10, label="") +
  theme_bw()

optns <- theme (
  plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size=14),
  axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=12),
  axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12, angle=90),
  #panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  #panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  #legend.position = c(0.5,0.5),
  legend.title = element_blank(),
  legend.text = element_text(size=12),
  legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "lines"),
  legend.key = element_blank()
)

sct2 +  ggtitle ( "Alzheimer") + optns



dput(head(human))
structure(list(mean_alzheimer = c(-0.0553750613, -0.0496918235, 
-0.0532426455, -0.0560890633, -0.0403871812, -0.0445302045), 
    stder_alzheimer = c(0.0069845669, 0.0081224212, 0.0071107644, 
    0.0065500585, 0.0055839854, 0.0066005107), Sample_size_alzheimer = c(16940L, 
    16940L, 16940L, 16940L, 16940L, 16940L), mean_other = c(-0.355721986, 
    -0.3934466529, -0.3391313067, -0.2490772834, -0.2482841254, 
    -0.3119203366), Stder_other = c(0.0594056892, 0.0696467566, 
    0.0618351559, 0.0538088139, 0.0498136972, 0.0585087673), 
    sample_size_other = c(256L, 256L, 256L, 256L, 256L, 256L), 
    P_value = c(1.17158668837528e-07, 2.47600854952653e-07, 1.13229142817565e-06, 
    0.0008543643, 0.0001136282, 1.82385100638758e-07), age1 = 1:6), .Names = c("mean_alzheimer", 
"stder_alzheimer", "Sample_size_alzheimer", "mean_other", "Stder_other", 
"sample_size_other", "P_value", "age1"), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example? it looks like no legend is showing up because you have colour set outside of `aes`. its hard to give an exact answer without seeing the format of your data

Comment: you haven't _mapped_ the colour with `aes()`, so ggplot2 won't create a legend. The idea would be to melt your data into long format, map colour to the variable, and have only two layers (one of points, one with smooth).

Comment: I try to upload a picture, but i donot have enough reputation to do it. Sorry.

Comment: If your example were reproducible, we could create the graph and upload it for you.

Comment: a picture isnt necessary. just a look at the data. it looks like you have 2 data.frames, 1 for alzheimers and 1 for other. These two data.frames should be combined (rbind) with another variable added to distinguish whether they are alzheimers or other. then you can melt the data if necessary and do all of the plotting in 1 layer with a code somewhat like ggplot() + geom_point(data = data, aes(x = age1, y = mean, colour = has_alzheimers)). this should not be plotted with 2 layers as this is one of the reasons why ggplot is so powerful

Comment: K, I update a data.frame

Comment: note that you define manual `fill` not `colour`

Comment: please dput(head(human)) so we can load the data easily. i would melt the data ie something like `melted = reshape:::melt(human[c("mean_alzheimers", "mean_other", "age1")], id.vars = "age1")` then plot it all in one go with aes(x = age1, y = value, colour = variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

melted <- melt(human[c("age1", "mean_alzheimer", "mean_other")], id.vars = "age1")

p <- ggplot(data = melted, aes(x = age1, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "loess")
```

Then add options to control colour, text, etc. as necessary.